# How to go move from one activity to a fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment

I have this code to move from a Fragment MyTask extends Fragment  to an Activity NewPage extends activity.

```
Intent i4=new Intent(getActivity(),NewPage.class);
startActivity(i4);
```

Now I want to go from NewPage.class back to my MyTask fragment. 
How can  I do that?

Comment: Which fragment this FragmentMyTask belongs to  ?

Comment: The question is not clear! Fragments are part of activity. So if you want to go back to previous activity then simplest approach is to just finish the current one (`getActivity().finish()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `finish()` method in the Activity to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Its a as simple you have to just call

```
finish()
```

method in your ***NewPage.class*** file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in your MainActivity and add FrameLayout to your activity_main.xml give the id to that .
Look the below code
"getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your xml_frmaelayout_id,new next_Fragment()).commit();"

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, getApplicationContext().getClass()));
```